# Why the info panel of collider is grey in unity3d?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I added a collider2D component to my Player to collide with the floor, but I noticed that the info panel which contains physic parameters like Friction, Bounciness is grey.I have to create a physics material by myself.So is that what it is(read only)?

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6a1I.png)

Comment: Those values are computed/ derived and are just there for convenience. The bounciness and friction values come from your physics material - you'd edit those values by changing them on your material, for example.

Answer (score 3):

Those values there are **only readable** and not able to be written on or to be changed.

Therefore if you would like to change them you need to make a `PhysicsMaterial2D` and apply it to the `CircleCollider2D`. You can also change the extents and centre of the `CircleCollider2D` by referencing the component in a script.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CircleCollider2D.html

Comment: Thanks.I changed the Friction and Bounciness and the changes were also showed in info panel.